# How do I cache/memoize a pandas DataFrame (expensive calculation) between requests within the Pyramid framework?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pyramid

```
class FindHits(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
       self.a = a
       self.b = b

    def calculate_hits():
       # Some expensive calculation using arguments self.a, and self.b
       df = pd.DataFrame()
       return df
```

I have a class that calculates some hits. The calculation and data retrieval process is rather expensive. So for a given set of parameters, I want to persist the results of "calculate_hits". I want to do so so that when these results are needed again moments or hours later, the calculations and retrieval does not need to happen again.

Naively, I tried putting the output results into the session object within the Pyramid framework. That did not work because the pandas Dataframe is too big...(And there might be other problems as well).

So how do I do this?

[For additional context: I am calculating some values in a pandas dataframe. I am then presenting the entire table in a jquery DataTable. I use the front-end to find the selected rows. I am sending back a list of selected rows. Now I want to go to those rows in the Dataframe and take information from that dataframe to save into a database.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define some sort of synchronized data store that can be shared across requests. If this isn't something external (redis, memcache, rdbms, ...) then you are probably asking about an in-memory store with locks. You can attach such a store to the `registry` and access it from each request. It is your responsibility to be aware of the threading issues here and lock the store appropriately such that 2 or more requests are not updating the store at once.

```
def main(...):
    config.registry.mystore = {'frame': pd.DataFrame()}

def view(request):
    frame = request.registry.mystore['frame']
```

As a side note, I have no idea if data frames in pandas are thread-safe but I'd bet that they aren't, so you'll need to address that somehow by serializing to a more primitive form and then deserializing to a new data frame per request.